# Highlight menu in scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

What I need help with is:
I want the menu to be on the scrollview and when I swipe it, the menu should become highlighted. For example; Menu is default color, once it is swiped, the color shall change to red.

I'm not to sure how I can do this, can anyone help?

UPDATE:

Basically what i mean to say is...

m trying to HILGHLIGHT the view that i scroll...

for example
[image]

the 1st image on scroll view is totally visible..i want this image to be highlighted.

then when scroll the next image...

2nd image shud come up and get highlighted..
[image]

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't understand your question...

Comment: @Manni I changed there question to make it more understandable now, but I still don't fully get what they mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)?
You could use

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    for (UIView *eachView in myViews) {
        CGFloat dif = offset - eachView.frame.origin.x; 
        if (dif > 0 && offset < eachView.frame.size.width)
            eachView.highlighted = YES;
        else
            eachView.highlighted = NO;
    }
}
```

note: this is not optimized... just an example